How to characterize software on hardware without having to run it?
To provide context, we are trying to characterize software in order to identify similarities between them and create clusters of similar software. When you can execute the software, the problem becomes more manageable (though not trivial). In the previous work we presented, we used Intel SDe and PERF, obtaining the individual executed instruction set (each instruction of x86 assembly code from the hardware on which it is executed and its internal characterization, which consists of about 30 subclasses) and the system resources used (PERF registers, which are not very relevant when it comes to characterization).
However, without executing the software, we can obtain the compiled program in x86 instructions and its control flow graph. From these, we can derive certain characteristics such as cyclomatic complexity, nesting level, general instruction types, total instructions, entropy, Halstead metrics, and so on.
While this is not a bad approach, it does not allow for strong characterization of the complete set of benchmarks that can be developed. It is obvious that software cannot be characterized exactly in the same way as it is done online.
What approaches do you consider relevant in this area? We're struggling to come up with other methods for characterizing software offline.
The ultimate goal is to optimize code during the compilation phase using LLVM passes. I've already done this multiple times and have managed to optimize certain benchmarks even more than with -O3, which is a generic optimization. However, the process can take up to a day to find the optimal sequence. Therefore, if we can obtain sequences for certain benchmarks (let's say 100, for example), when new software comes in, we could characterize it and find the closest match to one of the existing ones without having to execute it beforehand. This way, we can achieve better optimization tailored to that specific software on specific hardware based on what was previously discovered.
So, the aim is not to characterize types of software (games, databases, CNNs, path routing) but rather to group benchmarks (regardless of the intrinsic algorithm) based on their similarity at the hardware level.
